# RawFraction performance counters in c#

Tags: c#, performance

I am having issues using the RawFraction performance counter in my project. All I  want is to show a simple fraction of totalActionType1/totalActions.

So totalActions is my Rawbase counter and totalActionType1 is my Rawfraction counter.
I increment both the counters by 1 at specific places but how can I =see the ratio. I know I am doing something/everything wrong. The post on msdn is not helpful too.

I can see using the CounterSample to calculate the float value but then how can I show the float value as the counter raw value.

```
//Here is how I am incrementing the counters:

case CounterType.totalActions:
totalActions.Increment();
break;


case CounterType.totalActionType1:
totalActionType1.Increment();
break;

//Counter Creation:
totalActionType1 = new PerformanceCounter("Fract","RawFractionType", false);
totalActions = new PerformanceCounter("Fract","RawFractionBaseType", false);
var value = totalActionType1.NextValue();

//Counter Setup:
var countActionType1 = new CounterCreationData("RawFractionType", "", CounterType.RawFraction);
var countTotalActions= = new CounterCreationData("RawFractionBaseType", "", CounterType.RawBase);
categoryCollection.Add(countActionType1 ); 
categoryCollection.Add(countTotalActions);
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Fract", "", PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, categoryCollection);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to set up/read the counters?

Comment: I updated my post with the most recent code.

Comment: What is `_counters` defined as?

Answer (score 1):

So, I assume you created your counters like as follows in your installer class.  It's important that the base counter immediately follow the calculated counter.

```
            installer.Counters.Add(
                new CounterCreationData(counterName, counterDescription,
                                        PerformanceCounterType.RawFraction));
            installer.Counters.Add(
                new CounterCreationData(counterName + "-Base",
                                        counterDescription,
                                        PerformanceCounterType.RawBase));
```

If so, you can then query it by creating a `PerformanceCounter` instance for the `RawFraction` and calling `NextValue()` on it.

```
// for read-only access to it
var pc = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName, counterName, true);

var value = pc.NextValue();
```

For some counter types, you have to initially call `NextValue()` twice, to prime the calculation.  Also, keep in mind that `RawFraction` displays as a percentage, so if the value is 0.40 it will display as 40.0.

Comment: Calling NextValue after creating the counter didnt help. So, there is no way of seeing ratios?

Comment: @TechXie: What value (or exception) are you getting?

Comment: No exception. If I increment the rawfraction twice and increment my base 6 times, I see the value of rawFraction as 2 instead of percent value?

Comment: @TechXie: Are you calling `NextSample()` or `NextValue()`?

Comment: @TechXie: It's as if it's not considering your base, have you uninstalled and reinstalled your counters, and perhaps make the base counter name same as the counter name except end in Base?

Comment: Looks like that might be the case but I do delete and recreate the category each time.

Comment: @TechXie: Can we see more code?  I'm not sure how you have `_counters` defined in your code from your usage.

Comment: Thats right! I created a new question with code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825554/performance-counter-persists-its-state-even-after-deleting-the-category)